# the difference between 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm wondering what is the difference between these loops in 2D arrays:

```
for (int r = row - 1, c = column - 1; r >= 0 && c >= 0; r--, c--) {
    ...
}


for(int r=row-1;r>=0;r--){    
    for(int c=column-1;c>=0;c--){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int r = row - 1, c = column - 1; r >= 0 && c >= 0; r--, c--)
```

The first example is one loop that decrements both `r` and `c` every cycle, meaning that the indices `r` and `c` will draw a diagonal starting at `array[row-1][column-1]`.
[image]

```
for(int r=row-1;r>=0;r--){
    for(int c=column-1;c>=0;c--){
```

The second example calls a loop for columns for each index of row, so it will access *all* the indices `array[r][c]`
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! the reason I asked that question is I'm making a chess game, the loop i used (int r = row-1,c=column-1;r>=0&&c >=0;r--,c--)is for checking the left side diagonal chess, but how to write a loop checking right side diagonal, i have tried(int r =row+1;c=column-1;r>=0&&c>=0;r--;c--) but i doesn't wrok, cause outofboundary exception

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are asking for the difference between a single outer loop and a nested loop. The difference is that the single loop will iterate over the diagonal of the 2D array and the nested loops with iterate over every index of the array. For instance, if there are 6 rows and 4 columns then:

```
for (int r = row - 1, c = column - 1; r >= 0 && c >= 0; r--, c--) { 
     System.out.println(r + " " + c);
}
```

will yield:

```
5 3
4 2
3 1
2 0
```

Whereas the nested loop

```
for(int r=row-1; r>=0; r--) {
    for(int c=column-1; c>=0; c--) {
        System.out.println(r + " " + c);
    }
}
```

would yield

```
5 3
5 2
5 1
5 0
4 3
4 2
4 1
4 0
3 3
3 2
3 1
3 0
2 3
2 2
2 1
2 0
1 3
1 2
1 1
1 0
0 3
0 2
0 1
0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The first iterates for `n` times, where `n` is the least of `row` and `column`. The second iterates for `m` times, where `m` is `row` * `column`. That is

```
Math.min(row, column)
```

and

```
row * column
```

respectively.